# Angular radio buttons and custom input

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set up a form, with some radio buttons and a textarea for custom input. If I select custom input, and start typing it loses the radio selection and I must select the custom input again when I am done typing

http://jsbin.com/AMAniXu/2/edit

How can I ensure that selecting the radio next to the textarea and providing custom input maintains user selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different model object other than the object used in the `ng-value` of the checkbox

```
<input type="radio" data-ng-model="selectedEntry" data-ng-value="newText">
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" data-ng-model="newTextInput"></textarea>
```

And then you can grab the value in the model `newTextInput` when you click the submit button if the third one is selected.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eWiKidU/1/edit)**</kbd>

Comment: This does not bind textarea's value to the radio.

Comment: @CodeHater If the value of the radio button changed, it will be unselected. So they can't be coupled anyway.

Comment: @sza, so having the binding like my original example, is not possible and the custom input has to be bound to a different model?

Comment: @RyanHirsch you can just grab the value in the model `newTextInput` when you click the submit button if the third one is selected.  http://jsbin.com/eWiKidU/1/edit